# How to fix "Connection Refused" error while connecting with Selenium Docker Firefox container from Selenium RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-remotedriver, selenium-docker

I have been trying to learn Docker by creating a Docker container for Standalone-Firefox browser and connecting it using Selenium RemoteWebDriver.

I have installed a docker image and made sure it is running. I am trying to access Google.com and print the title.

However, I am getting "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure." error.

Docker Image is correctly setup

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

![Docker image is running successfully](E:\Udemy Courses\SDET Architect\Successful Docker Running.JPG)

```
package dockerValidation;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class ChromeStandAloneTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");      
        // Static Class named DesiredCapabilities is used. No need to create object
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        // RemoteWebDriver to run test on Cloud, Docker, etc
        RemoteWebDriver rwd = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);

        rwd.get("http://google.com");
        System.out.println(rwd.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Expected Result (Eclipse Console)

> May 15, 2019 6:36:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox
>   INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`
>   May 15, 2019 6:36:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected Dialect: OSS
>   Google

Actual Result

> May 15, 2019 6:36:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox
>   INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-QJQOV4L', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>   Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
>       at dockerValidation.ChromeStandAloneTest.main(ChromeStandAloneTest.java:20)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:4444
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
>       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>       ... 4 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>       at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
>       ... 26 more

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same, restarting docker helped me. Not the best solution, but it works.